# DB2 insert without some values

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

I have a script which return rows from a table , using which i migrate data/create new tables.
for one of the tables , because it has null values :it returns me some thing like:

```
insert into table1(column 1, column 2,column 3, column 4) values (abc,,,cdf);
```

will this insert query work as such or i need to take care of null values.

Edited :my script does this

1. do a selct query and pick columns from an old separate DB
2. print an output file where insert query has columns values passed from RESULTSET of above Select statement.

later i use this to directly update new tables in new database.

Comment: You obviously need to take care of NULLs. This query will not function.

Comment: The statement will **not** work. You need to fix the script that generates those invalid statements.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your requirement ,You can write script like this

```
insert into table2(column 1, column 2,column 3, column 4)
select column 1,column 2,column 3,column 4 from table1
where isnull(column 1,'')<>'' and isnull(column 2,'')<>'' and isnull(column 3,'')<>'' and     isnull(column 4,'')<>''
```